# Remove icon not appearing in dropzone

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am working with Dropzone in a Laravel project. I have successfully implemented it but the remove icon is not appearing after I upload an image.

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFileUpload"></div>
</div>
```

```js
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file",
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  maxFilesize: 5, // MB
  init: function() {},
  accept: function(file, done) {},
  removedfile: function(file) {},
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure but maybe Dropzone is already initialised when you set the addRemoveLinks option. Can you try to do it while initialising like this (in your domReady):

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#dropzoneFileUpload', {
    paramName: "file",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    init: function() {},
    accept: function(file, done) {},
    removedfile: function(file) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after the addRemoveLinks add the following lines to the options

```
removedfile: function (file) {
 var _ref;
 return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;        
},
```

Comment: Works perfeclty, I just fixed a little bug var _ref;
 return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;